# How to create a mutable copy of an immutable `List[List[Int]` in Scala?

Tags: list, scala, mutable

I want to create a mutable copy of an immutable  `List[List[Int]`. What I was thinking of was using a mutable `ListBuffer` and loop through the immutable array and append each item to it, but perhaps there is a more efficient or cleaner way?

Comment: Do you want a `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]` or a flat one?

Comment: or even a `ListBuffer[List[Int]]`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Apologies for the late reply. I want a`ListBuffer[List[Int]]`  like in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear.
if you need `ListBuffer[List[Int]]` here you go:

```
list.to[ListBuffer]
```

If you want to get `ListBuffer[ListBuffer[Int]]` use the next:

```
list.map(_.to[ListBuffer]).to[ListBuffer]
```

if you want to obtain `ListBuffer[Int]`, you can use:

```
list.to[ListBuffer].flatten
```